# getting SQLAlchemy to return times in UTC

Tags: sqlalchemy, timezone

I can't figure out how to get SQLAlchemy to return times in UTC.  I have a model with a datetime field with `timezone=True`.  I know that Postgres stores all timezones internally in UTC, but when the date comes back out it's shifted to the timezone I'm.  The python datetime object has it's `tzinfo` set to `psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=-240, name=None)` when SQLAlchemy retrieves it from Postgres.  I know I could just convert to UTC once I get the date out of SQLalchemy, but that just sounds tedious since I'll be using datetimes everywhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the postgres database doesn't have a timezone set? Log in to postgres and run:

```
test_db=> show timezone;
TimeZone 
---------
US/Central
```

This will cause all times output from SQLAlchemy to have central timezone. You want to make sure this value is something like this instead:

```
test_db=> show timezone;
 TimeZone
----------
 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQLAlchemy will return times in UTC. You should remove timezone=True (or set it to False).